# Workflow: How to Create/Update an Item if it Exists or Does Not

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have 2 lists: List A and List B.

My goal is to copy over an item in List A to List B.

In SharePoint Designer 2007, here are the available Workflow commands:

```
- Create List Item
- Update List Item
- Copy List Item
```

Which command creates a list item in List B "if it does not exist", and updates the list item in List B "if it exists"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same question yesterday at work.  Here is how I solved it today.

Lists:
Parent: List A
Target: List B

Create the workflow and associate it with the Parent List.
The workflow can start however you please.

You will need 3 Steps in your workflow.

Step 1: Create a workflow variable and use a lookup to set the variable to the Title (this can be any unique field) of the Target list. I chose the Title field because I knew it would be unique to each item.
No conditions required.
Action: Set Variable:Foo to Bar (where Bar is the field you chose to match against)

Step 2: Check if the variable you just assigned equals the title (or unique field of your choice) of the item you just created/edited in the Parent list. 
So your condition will be:  If Variable:Foo equals Bar (where Bar is the field you chose) 
and your Action will be:  Stop the workflow

Step 3: If we make it to step 3, then our variable did not match an existing item
No conditions are required in this step.
Action: Copy Item then stop the workflow.

That's it!

Additionally, if you'd like to loop through your lists and process everything, this article was very helpful for me:
[SharePoint Looping Workflow - How to: Loop through and process all items in a list](http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-looping-workflow-how-to-loop.html)

I hope this makes sense.  And I hope it works for you as well as it has for me!

Comment: I've yet to try this, but your steps seem to be straightforward. Thanks for making it easy! Once I get it to work, I'll mark you up.

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow will need to check list B first.  If the item exists then it will need to "Update List Item".  If it does not exists, it will need to "Copy List Item".

So how can you check?

There's a great article on doing that here:
http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/08/spd-workflow-test-if-value-exists-in.html